QTabelView cell Tool Tip not handling rich text
Firstly, I have tested that QToolTip works with rich text (as described my PyQt6), and if you simply use .setToolTip() on a QWidget rich text works file. However:
My QTableView is connected to an QAbstractTableModel, which in the data() function returns a rich text string from a Qt.ItemDataRole.ToolTipRole request, however it is being handled as plain text, instead of rich text in the Tool Tip window that pops up.
How do I fix this?
So far cannot find any way to make this work
